# BASH SCRIPT: Combining Permutations of Contents in a Directory

Tags: linux, bash, algorithm

I'm currently trying to combine the contents of all **.rule** files in the **rules** directory.

For example:

```
./rules
    ./numbersFirst.rule
    ./numbersLast.rule
    ./lettersFirst.rule
    etc.
```

Each of these files has about 1,000 rules. I need to write a bash script that can output all permutations of each of these rules.

For all the singles, it would just be:

```
cat rules/*.rule >> ruleSet
```

Is there any way to do this programmatically and cleverly? For example:

```
    for rule1 in rules/*.rule
    do
        for rule2 in rules/*.rule
        do
            if [ $rule1 != $rule 2 ]
            then
                #read both files and output "$line_rule1 $line_rule2"
                #Magic here?
            fi
        done
    done
```

What about for permutations of 3, 4, ... n files, each with 1,000 lines each? The ideal is to programmatically do this with n files so that I can simple add to the directory and rebuild from this script. Obviously it will be a LOT of combinations!

Comment: While I did say PERMUTATIONS, after a little thought, I'm really looking for the COMBINATIONS of each line, from each file, as it doesn't matter the order of the arguments, only that each combination occurred.

Comment: Do you want the power set of the set of all the rules?

Comment: Can you show some sample input and the expected result? It's not clear from your description. And if you want to clarify what you mean, edit the question, don't put it in comments.

Comment: Do you always want a line with 2 rules as output or 1 rule from each file (each line n rules when you have n files) ? Or do you want each possible combination of 2 rules (with one file already 500.000  combinations). Does the order matter (is rule1,rule2 different from rule2,rule1) ?

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me show you expected results.

The order does not matter, just the results - I ordered them in the most logical (human) way I could think.   http://pastebin.com/J74r3989

Answer (score 1):

You can compute cartesian product with [GNU `parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) if available :

```
#!/bin/bash

YOUR_DIR="./rules"

ARGS="::: "
NUM=0
for file in $YOUR_DIR/*.rule; do
    ARGS="$ARGS $(cat $file | tr "\n" " ") ::: "
    NUM=$((NUM+1))
    INDEX="$INDEX {$NUM}"
done

if [ ! -z "$ARGS" ]; then
    parallel --no-notice -P1 echo $INDEX $ARGS
fi
```

Or through only recurrence with associative array :

```
#!/bin/bash

dim=()

YOUR_DIR="./rules"
NUM=0

for file in $YOUR_DIR/*.rule; do
    ARGS="$(cat $file | tr "\n" " ")"
    dim[$NUM]="$ARGS"
    NUM=$((NUM+1))
done

for i in "${!dim[@]}"
do
  echo "key  : $i"
  echo "value: ${dim[$i]}"
done

function iterate {

    local index="$2"

    if [ "${index}" == "${#dim[@]}" ]; then

        for (( i=0; i<=${index}; i++ ))
        do
            echo -n "${items[$i]} "
        done
        echo ""
    else
        for element in ${dim[${index}]}; do
            items["${index}"]="${element}"
            local it=$((index+1))
            iterate items[@] "$it"
        done
    fi
}

declare -a items=("")
iterate "" 0
```

You can find a generalization [here](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/a16f68cf508ae2c07b59)